# AngularJs appending options to select box

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am new to AngularJs. I am having problem in appending options to select boxes created by javascript. Following is my code.

```
var inputElements = $('<div><label style="float:left;">' + i + '</label><select ng-model="object" class="form-control sel" style="width:300px; float:right; margin-right:75px;"> <option>select</option></select></div></br></br>');
var temp = $compile(inputElements)($scope);
$('#projOrder').append(temp);
$scope.object = object;
//for(var opt=0; opt<selOptLabels.length; opt++) {
$('.sel').append('<option ng-repeat="obj in object" value="'+
{{obj.value}}+'">'+{{obj.value}}+'</option>');
```

I am getting this error:- SyntaxError: invalid property id

Hi, I am posting json example. This is just a small part of json in my case.

```
    "ProjectOrder": {
"Connect direct required": {
  "value": "N",
  "id": "STR_15523_62"
},
"Cores": {
  "value": ".5",
  "id": "NUM_15523_50"
},
"Permanent data in GB": {
  "value": "100",
  "id": "NUM_15523_56"
},
"Description": {
  "value": "AZBNL azbngb",
  "id": "STR_15523_2"
},
"Order Id": {
  "value": "15523",
  "id": "INT_15523_96"
},
"Project cost center": {
  "value": "N",
  "id": "STR_15523_66"
},
"Project debitor": {
  "value": "N",
  "id": "STR_15523_64"
},
"Project OE": {
  "value": "N",
  "id": "STR_15523_57"
},
"Project SITE": {
  "value": "N",
  "id": "STR_15523_59"
},
"Project Status": {
  "value": "RFC",
  "id": "STR_15523_54",
  "dropdown": [
    {
      "value": "IW",
      "label": "In Work"
    },
    {
      "value": "RFC",
      "label": "Ready for Creation"
    },
    {
      "value": "CR",
      "label": "Created"
    },
    {
      "value": "FC",
      "label": "Failed"
    }
  ]
},
"Project Type (paas, miner)": {
  "value": "paas",
  "id": "STR_15523_37",
  "dropdown": [
    {
      "value": "paas",
      "label": "PaaS Project"
    },
    {
      "value": "miner",
      "label": "Miner Project"
    }
  ]
},
"WORK data in GB": {
  "value": "100",
  "id": "NUM_15523_55"
}
```

}

Now I have to create input fields and dropdown menus(if there is a dropdown menu) with json data

Comment: I dont see any reference to `property id`. Are you sure that problem in this piece of code?

Comment: Yes I am sure that the problem is in appending option line.

Comment: In explorer, the error is expecting string or number

Comment: Why are you use `{{ }}` in `<option ng-repeat="obj in object" value="'+{{obj.value}}+'">'+{{obj.value}}+'</option` if you just concatinating a string? Wher is your template starts?

Comment: I think this is must in angularjs. Btw the object has following structure:-
[{"id": "1", "value": "abc"},{"id": "1", "value": "abc"},{"id": "1", "value": "abc"}]

Comment: Try compiling the options as did for select and then append

Comment: I have tried its giving the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should not be hand-constructing HTML like that. It's best if you use a template and let the template engine handle the heavy lifting.

I also noticed that you're using `object` as the `ng-model`. Instead you should have a separate variable which will hold the selected value.

Here's a better way of doing this--in an .html file:

```
<div ng-repeat="object in listOfObjects"
    <label style="float: left">{{ $index }}</label>
    <select ng-model="selectedValues[$index]" class="form-control sel"
        style="width:300px; float:right; margin-right:75px;"
        ng-options="obj.value for obj in object"></select>
</div>
```

Then in whatever controller you have set up in JavaScript:

```
// this will be the list of selected values
$scope.selectedValues = new Array(list.length);
// this would be the array that each `object` is part of
$scope.listOfObjects = list;
```

This isn't the most elegant solution, but basically what I've done is construct an array that is the same length as the list of objects. Angular templates have a special variable `$index` when you're in an `ng-repeat` which tracks the current index of the array you're looping through.

So when a user changes the selected value of the 3rd select box (index 2), `$scope.selectedValues[2]` would be set to the selected option.

EDIT: on transforming the JSON to an array:

```
var list = Object.keys(json).map(function(jsonKey) {
    return {
        name: jsonKey,
        label: json[jsonKey].label,
        value: json[jsonKey].value
    };
});`
```

Comment: Hi, It is not possible in my case to use the template. Because I have to create dropdown boxex on the basis of json data. If there is dropdown object only then it creates dropdown.

Comment: do you have a more complete example then? you should be able to use JSON data to power this--I do this all the time.

Comment: Hi, I have uploaded the json data. Please have a look.@gonzofish

Comment: ng-options can handle that (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) look at "for object sources"

or you could transform the data (look at my edited answer)

Comment: Hi, I need this kind of stuff. Please have a look into my plunker and help me to get values in first and second dropdown thank you
plnkr.co/edit/DbPfcEXFF7baojQ8qqmW?p=preview

Comment: Well I think this is the best solution. I am trying to do it like this. Thank You

Comment: Hi, @gonzofish I have solved my problem according to your suggestions. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: great! glad that did it for you!

Comment: Hi, Now i have another problem. Do you know how to get values of all the input fields using angularjs? I know how to do this with jquery but not angularjs. Please help me

Comment: That's what no-model is for. You should really run through an AngularJS tutorial. It seems like the basic concepts of the framework aren't in your grasp.

Answer (score 1):

So.. there are a number of reasons why that won't work. The provided code wouldn't even work because of the template brackets that you are trying to append to your html string...

```
$('.sel').append('<option ng-repeat="obj in object" value="' +{{obj.value}}+'">'+{{obj.value}}+'</option>');
```

Is there a reason that you are trying build your markup in js?

It's also advised not to use jquery inside angular controllers. If you have jquery loaded the jQuery object is available through angular.element, otherwise angular uses jQuery light.

Rather than enumerate on the other issues here, I put together this basic example of how a select works in Angular

https://codepen.io/parallaxisjones/pen/BRKebV

Also, you should consult the angular documentation before posting questions to stack overflow.  The docs provide a pretty clear example of how to use ng-repeat in a select. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

**EDIT**:  I updated my codepen with an example of fetching JSON data with an HTTP GET request

**EDIT**: updated codepen with provided data example, iterating over object with (key, value) in json syntax in ng-repeat

Comment: Yes, I have to create input fields on the basis of json data.

Comment: if that is the case you should fetch the data in the controller, and set it on the $scope variable on success.  in this way you can access it in the HTML markup.  checkout my codepen for an example

Comment: @MuhammadUmar check out the pen now, I think that may clear some things up for you

Comment: Hi I am trying to implement this. Can you please implement this code on javascript based template?

Comment: @MuhammadUmar I don't understand your question. What do you mean by javascript based template?

Comment: Actually I am creating template using javascript on the basis of json data, where i find dropdown in json dat, i create dropdown otherwise i have to create input fields

Comment: @MuhammadUmar you are misusing angular then and over-complicating your life. 

 One of the intentions of angular is to stay away from writing HTML dynamically in javascript as you have in your example.

Angular intends to bring JS code into the HTML to be able to iterate and use template strings directly in the HTML markup. do you have an HTML file or is the code that you provided the way that all your HTML is written?

I updated my pen with an example doing what you ask but I don't recommend doing it that way.  This is a misuse of angular

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the late reply. I have applied your idea. Its working but there is a miner problem. I have created a plunker. Can you please tell me that why its not getting the properties of first object in first dropdown. Please have a look. I need your help. Thank You. @parallaxis

https://plnkr.co/edit/DbPfcEXFF7baojQ8qqmW?p=preview